# Livewire form submit with multiple wire:model input name

Tags: laravel-livewire

How can I let livewire know that a model is a particular modal

I have this in my livewire component

```
public $itemname; 
public function updateReceivedKg()
{
  
       $this->validate([
            'itemname' => 'required',
        ]);
  dump($this->itemname)


}
```

On livewire view, I have this

```
@foreach($result->products as $index=>$data)

    <form  wire:submit.prevent="updateReceivedKg()">
          <div class="input-group">
               <input required  wire:model.defer="itemname" type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-append">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Update</button>
                                </span>

                               </div>
    </form>
                     
@endforeach
```

After generating the form, I have about 11 forms. The issue is that livewire always submit the last itemname that was entered. For example, if on the first form, I entered "Mango" and go to another form and enter "Apple", if I go back to the form which I have already written "Mango" and click the submit (without typing anything) button, if I dump the submitted form and check the itemname, it shows it is the Apple. This is wrong because I submitted the Mango form.

In normal Laravel, I have no issue with this type of form submission. It will detect which form I submitted.
Please how can I achieve the same result using Livewire

Answer (score 0):

You have the same itemname for a lot of elements. You should probably append the index to the modelname.

```
public $itemname1;
public $itemname2; // etc..
```

```
@foreach($result->products as $index=>$data)

    <form  wire:submit.prevent="updateReceivedKg()">
          <div class="input-group">
               <input required  wire:model.defer="itemname{{$index}}" type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-append">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Update</button>
                                </span>

                               </div>
    </form>
                     
@endforeach
```